# kernel module Vs. user-space application which one is faster?

Tags: linux, performance, module, linux-kernel, arm

Is it true to say that if I need fast implementation and faster runtime I should implement my code in a kernel module ? Or is it unnecessarily true to say that and the same code using ioctls and syscalls may run faster from user-sapce?  I can't go for the two solutions and testbanch them since it is a design question that should be answered in advance.

Comment: I believe that when possible you should avoid hacking the kernel (which is much more brittle to develop). And we could help only if we understood what kind of application you want to code.

Comment: Also, coding a kernel module is considerably more difficult than coding a user-space application....

Comment: You need to provide more details about what is being done.  As **Basile** notes, there is a price for developing as a module.  If the code is straight line **ARM**, then using `nice` can give priority to a user task and there is no benefit to using kernel code.  Some particular use cases maybe faster in the kernel.  For instance audio/video processing will have data available in kernel and copying larger amounts of data can be avoided.  There is no way to answer the question without a little more information on the task.

Comment: artless hits the nail on the head with this.  in general, CPU time is CPU time.  unless the computer's cores are all saturated, then you won't really see any increase in performance by offloading large amounts of work into kernel space.  indeed, if your code blocks the kernel thread (whose code is expected to be rapid and efficient), you may notice degraded performance for the entire system.

Comment: There is far to little information in this question to make that judgement call.  It may be that for the IO you're doing, user-space is perfectly adequate.   Kernel development is HARD and has all manner of deployment and licensing issues to deal with.  In my opinion, there would need to be a pretty compelling reason to do so - e.g. needing to do something that is just not possible in user-space.

Comment: @0x90 For performance gains you have lots of real-time scheduling options and you should avoid kernel programming for speeding up an application, chances are as artless said, you will end up slowing things down. If you explain your use-case a bit more may be we can answer the question more effectively

Comment: i think a module and an application are different things with different purposes.
Check this text for more information: http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-2-sect-3